# How to configure submit elements in one place in ZF2

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I create submit buttons for my ZF2 forms using array notation similar to the [skeleton application tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html):

```
     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'submit',
         'type' => 'Submit',
         'attributes' => array(
             'value' => 'Go',
             'id' => 'submitbutton',
         ),
     ));
```

If I expand my project from lists of Albums to lists of Books, lists of DVDs, lists of Pets, lists of YuGiOhCards, etc.; each new module requires its own form.  It's easy enough to rewrite the same code to add a submit button to each form; but to ensure consistency, it makes sense to code a submit button once in a single location and call it from each of the form classes.

If I want to reuse a "global" submit button, where do I code it and how do I call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the form element manager; which is a specialised service manager for form elements providing all the usual reusable services and DI using factories.

For example, you could provide your button as a service.

```
'form_elements' => [
    'factories' => [
        'MySubmitButton' => 'MyModule\Form\Element\MySubmitButtonFactory',
    ],
],
```

Then create the factory.

```
namespace MyModule\Form\Element;

use Zend\Form\Element\Submit; 

class MySubmitButtonFactory
{
    public function __invoke($formElementManager, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        $element = new Submit('submit');
        $element->setAttributes([
            'value' => 'Go',
            'id' => 'submitbutton'
        ]);
        return $element;
    }
}
```

When you need to add this to a form you should fetch the element from the `FormElementManager` service first.

```
$formElementManager = $serviceManager->get('FormElementManager');
$button = $formElementManager->get('MySubmitButton');
```

Or when you need to add via config in a form, the form factory will use the `type` key and pull from the `FormElementManager` for you.

```
 $this->add([
     'name' => 'submit',
     'type' => 'MySubmitButton',
 ]);
```

Comment: Looks good, but I'm struggling to make it work.  Message "Zend\Form\FormElementManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for … " leads me to believe that I "must not directly instantiate [the] form class, but rather get an instance of it through the `Zend\Form\FormElementManager`," according to http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html#creating-custom-elements.  This opens a new can of worms because I need to inject the ObjectManager for Doctrine.

Comment: If you are adding the submit in the same manor as my last example then you will also need to request the *form* via the form element manager.

Comment: This is because the form element manager will inject a configured `FormFactory` into the *form* which then allows it to create other *custom* elements such as `MySubmitButton`. If you use `new Form()` the *configured* form factory will never be injected.

Comment: I'm trying find a way to work around that.  See my question [How to pass a Doctrine ObjectManager to a form through ZF2 FormElementManager]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34551965/how-to-pass-a-doctrine-objectmanager-to-a-form-through-zf2-formelementmanager).

Comment: @jcropp I just answered that question; which would also fix this one :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

Just create trait which will contain `addSubmit()` method

```
protected function addSubmit()
{
    $this->add([
        'name' => 'submit',
        'type' => 'Submit',
        'attributes' => [
            'value' => 'Go',
            'id' => 'submitbutton',
        ],
    ]);
}
```

and use it in your form.

```
class MyForm extends Form
{
    use SubmitButtonFormTrait;

    // ...

    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        parent::__construct('customName');

        // ...

        $this->addSubmit();
    }
}
```