# How to pass a Doctrine ObjectManager to a form through ZF2 FormElementManager

Tags: forms, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I would like to create custom form elements in ZF2, which requires FormElementManager.  I am currently using Doctrine Hydrator in the form creation as shown in [this tutorial](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md).  In this method, an ObjectManager object is created in the controller and passed to the new form when it is instantiated:

```
public function editAction()
{
    // Get your ObjectManager from the ServiceManager
    $objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

    // Create the form and inject the ObjectManager
    $form = new UpdateBlogPostForm($objectManager);

    // …
```

#### the update form:

```
namespace Application\Form;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class UpdateBlogPostForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('update-blog-post-form');

        // The form will hydrate an object of type "BlogPost"
        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager));

        // Add the user fieldset, and set it as the base fieldset
        $blogPostFieldset = new BlogPostFieldset($objectManager);
        $blogPostFieldset->setUseAsBaseFieldset(true);
        $this->add($blogPostFieldset);

        // … add CSRF and submit elements …

        // Optionally set your validation group here
    }
}
```

#### the BlogPost fieldset:

```
namespace Application\Form;

use Application\Entity\BlogPost;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class BlogPostFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('blog-post');

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager))
             ->setObject(new BlogPost());

        // … add fieldset elements …

    }

    // … public function getInputFilterSpecification() …

}
```

Unfortunately, in order to use ZF2's FormElementManager, the [ZF2 manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html#creating-custom-elements) says, "The second catch is that you *must not* directly instantiate your form class, but rather get an instance of it through the Zend\Form\FormElementManager;" so I have to get the form like this:

```
 public function editAction()
 {
     $sl = $this->getServiceLocator();
     $form = $sl->get('FormElementManager')->get('\Application\Form\UpdateBlogPostForm');
```

Is there a way to pass the ObjectManager object `$objectManager` to the form through `FormElementManager`, or is there a way to create the object within the form so the hydrator and the fieldset can use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### DoctrineEntityHydratorFactory

A factory that creates the hydrator and injects the object manager.

```
namespace MyModule\Stdlib\Hydrator;

use DoctrineORMModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineEntity;

class DoctrineEntityHydratorFactory
{
    public function __invoke($hydratorPluginManager, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        $serviceManager = $hydratorPluginManager->getServiceLocator();
        $objectManager  = $serviceManager->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

        return new DoctrineEntity($objectManager);
    }
}
```

#### BlogPostFieldset

A reusable fieldset that contains all the elements for a Blog post and uses the `EntityHydrator` to hydrate a `BlogPost` entity.

```
namespace MyModule\Form;

use Zend\Form\Fieldset;

class BlogPostFieldsetFactory
{
    public function __invoke($formElementManager, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        $serviceManager = $formElementManager->getServiceLocator();
        $hydrator = $serviceManager->get('HydratorManager')->get('DoctrineEntityHydrator');

        $fieldset = new Fieldset('blog_post');
        $fieldset->setHydrator($hydrator);
        $fieldset->setObject(new BlogPost);

        //... add fieldset elements.
        $fieldset->add(['...']);
        //...

        return $fieldset;
    }
}
```

#### UpdateBlogPostFormFactory

A factory to create the blog post update form. This attaches the fieldset and sets [the `use_as_base_fieldset` option which allows it to use the fieldsets hydrator](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/in-depth-guide/zend-form-zend-form-fieldset.html#zend-form-and-zend-stdlib-hydrator-working-together).

```
namespace MyModule\Form;

class UpdateBlogPostFormFactory
{
    public function __invoke($formElementManager, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        $form = new Form('update_blog_post);

        //...
        $factory = new \Zend\Form\Factory($formElementManager);
        $form->setFormFactory($factory);
        $form->add([
            'name' => 'blog_post',
            'type' => 'BlogPostFieldset',
            'options' => [
                'use_as_base_fieldset' => true,   
            ]
        ]);
        //...

        return $form;
    }
}
```

You will also need to register the services with the required managers in `module.config.php`.

```
return [
    'form_elements' => [
        'factories' => [
            'UpdateBlogPostForm' => 'MyModule\Form\UpdateBlogPostFormFactory',
            'BlogPostFieldset' => 'MyModule\Form\BlogPostFieldsetFactory',
        ],
    ],
    'hydrators' => [
        'factories' => [
            'DoctrineEntityHydrator' => 'MyModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineEntityHydratorFactory',
        ],
    ],
];
```

So with the above you can request your form in the controller.

```
$form = $formElementManager->get('UpdateBlogPostForm');
```

Comment: Thanks, @AlexP.  In implementing your solution I found that I wasn't thorough with my question.  In the Doctrine hydrator model that I'm trying to work around, the ObjectManager object `$objectManager` is also used to inject the fieldset into the form.  I've expanded my question to show this.  Should the fieldset now be injected into the form in the `EditProjectPhaseFactory`?  How?

Comment: @jcropp If you have multiple forms  (update/create/edit) you can create a reusable fieldset as shown in my edit. This fieldset actually does the hydration, you just need to attach it to each form.

Comment: I keep getting an error message: `Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException` The file is `…\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:529`, the message is `Zend\Form\FormElementManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for BlogPostFieldset`, and the last line of the stack trace is `…\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager.php(103): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('BlogPostFieldse...', true)`.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I've checked all my spelling and tried renaming with lower-case to rule out naming issues.

Comment: I've added to theform factory; You could also use `$form->add($formElementManager->get('BlogPostFieldset))'`

Comment: Awesome.  The last piece to my puzzle is how to add a collection to the fieldset factory.  @AlexP, can you help me with my new question [How to use collections in a fieldset factory in ZF2]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684416/how-to-use-collections-in-a-fieldset-factory-in-zf2).